# Using a memory profiler that monitors multiple projects

Tags: c#, silverlight, memory-management, profiler

I am working on a Silverlight 4 project and there is a major memory leak apparently left in before I took over. I have tried two different profilers that hook into VIsual Studio 2010 and I noticed that the data wasn't changing between snapshots. It was then I realized that it wasn't showing most of my data, nor any custom classes.

What I believe is happening is that it is only showing my memory usage for the "startup project" but there are a bunch of other supporting projects that are actually doing the heavy lifting that contain the leak. Is there a profiler that can show multiple project's memory usage?

So far I have used ANTS and something from memprofiler.com . I tried WinDbg but I couldn't get it to work and all the instructions for using it seem fairly old.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit:
The solution found was to properly set up ANTS to point at the website hosting the application which would finally show everything. The debugged local version would not show the same data.

Edit 2: 
Connecting to the silverlight app on the web seems to be as good as it gets.

Comment: On any profiler I worked you, before profiling something you basically chose the binaries whcih you're going to profile. Seems strange to me then ANTS doesn't have that kind of possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do some fixing to the project through the help of ANTS, their support page [RedGate Support](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Memory%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/amp_unmanaged_use.htm&toc=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/toc1286226.htm) helped some but I just don't think they have the best recommendations for how to profile a Silverlight App.

From what I have been hearing its just not that easy to profile a silverlight app currently, and what information I was getting from ANTS was I guess all that I can expect without using more "hands on" tools. In case someone else needs to profile in silverlight when I continue getting rid of memory leaks I'll be working off these sites below

[Hunting Down Memory Leaks in Silverlight](http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/hunting-down-memory-leaks-in-silverlight/)

[MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with trying to attach to many processes is that the application would have to communicate with multiple COM profilers (1 per process) and this complexity may not have been built in - however nothing should be stopping you run multiple hosts/profilers at the same time.

NOTE: I've used ClrProfiler4 to find memory leaks in a silverlight app (found we had (re)discovered the context menu memory leak in the Silverlight toolkit)

It worked quite well, not the prettiest of profilers but what do you expect for free.

Comment: when I tried running the profiler on the web version of the silverlight program, the program sat forever on the loading screen making no progress. But I was hoping you could further explain the context menu memory leak you mentioned to make sure that is not the issue (new to silverlight). From the data I am getting from ANTS it seems that a lot is leaking and I can't find a common ground for them. So far the solid facts I have are that any time I navigate within the app the app grows and what I get the most new instances of is weak references.

Comment: Scratch that, I seem to have patched up the major source of the leak. Its more of a trickle that seems to occur in a pattern I can't identify (instead of every change in navigation resulting in a growth, its more like every 10th change)

Comment: The memory leak we had was related to a message handler for mouse events, constantly += with no responding -= (a classic mistake but annoying in3rd party code)